# Вылетает приложение [Admob / Unity / Android]

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

Вылетает приложение при реквесте на объявление, плагин установлен последней версии, код с официального руководства. В консоли все гладко.

```
 InterstitialAd interstitial;

 public void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string adUnitId = "код объявления с сайта admob";
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }

 public void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }

 void Start () 
   {
        string appId = "код приложения с сайта";
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

Comment: Стэктрейс ошибки?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, где их посмотреть?

Comment: Я не знаю, в чем вы работаете. В Андроид Студио - logcat.

Comment: в заголовке и в метках топика есть) работаю в Unity

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это:

Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve

Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve